# How to construct Array Series without going through List?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I can do this:

```
let mut col1: ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder<Float64Type> = ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder::new(
    "array", 
    1,
    2, 
    DataType::Float64);

col1.append_slice(&[1.1,2.2]);
col1.append_slice(&[2.1,2.2]);
col1.append_slice(&[3.1,2.2]);
let s = col1.finish().into_series();
let sa = s.cast(&DataType::Array(Box::new(DataType::Float64), 2)).unwrap();
let df = DataFrame::new(vec![sa]);
println!("{:?}",df)
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────┐
│ array         │
│ ---           │
│ array[f64, 2] │
╞═══════════════╡
│ [1.1, 2.2]    │
│ [2.1, 2.2]    │
│ [3.1, 2.2]    │
└───────────────┘
```

but it seems silly to make a list just to later cast it to an Array. I found `FixedSizeListNumericBuilder` in polars-core/src/chunked_array_builder/fixed_size_list.rs but I don't know how to use it.

A couple bonus questions:

1. in the `ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder` what are `capacity` and `values_capacity`? They don't seem to be binding. (ie I can make more horizontal and vertical values than are specified there.)
2. Why do I have to wrap `DataType::Float64` in `Box::new()`?

Answer (score 0):

`FixedSizeListNumericBuilder` is not exported (`pub(crate)`), so you cannot use it. Its methods are also mostly `unsafe`, so it looks like it wasn't meant to be exposed either.

> in the `ListPrimitiveChunkedBuilder` what are `capacity` and `values_capacity`? They don't seem to be binding. (ie I can make more horizontal and vertical values than are specified there.)

Capacity in Rust usually refers to the amount of allocated memory. It's not a hard limit since allocations can grow, but it usually affects performance. It is a good idea to predict the desired capacity if you can.

> Why do I have to wrap `DataType::Float64` in `Box::new()`?

Because `DataType::Array` recursively contains a `DataType` (for the elements type), and recursive types must include an indirection, otherwise they would have an infinite size.